# Code blocking when sending back data with Socket

Tags: python, networking

I'm currently trying to send an image from my Raspberry Pi to my pc and send something back to the PI with the Socket library. Sending the image works, if I don't send something. However, if I try sending a response to the PI, both codes seem to get stuck. Can anyone help me with this ?

This is my Server code:

```
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('192.168.137.1', 5005))
server_socket.listen(5)
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"                # om tekst van tensorflow import niet te laten zien
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("C:/Users/antho/Bachelorproef/Models/(BLOK1&2&3)3-conv-128-nodes-2-dense-1585522274")

print("model loaded")

IMG_SIZE = 100

while (1):
    client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
    print("Connected to - ",address,"\n")
    fp = open("C:/Users/antho/Bachelorproef/Socket_Tests/test.jpeg",'wb')
    while True:
        strng = client_socket.recv(512)
        if not strng:
            break
        fp.write(strng)
    fp.close()

    print("Image received")
    img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/antho/Bachelorproef/Socket_Tests/test.jpeg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE , IMG_SIZE))
    img = np.array(img).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
    prediction = model.predict(img)
    print(np.argmax(prediction))

    pred = str(np.argmax(prediction))
    client_socket.sendall(bytes(pred, "utf-8"))
    print("send pred")
```

And this is my client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# TCP client example
import socket,os
import io
import time
import picamera

# Create an in-memory stream
my_stream = io.BytesIO()
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.start_preview()
    # Camera warm-up time
    time.sleep(0.2)
    camera.capture(my_stream, format='jpeg')

my_stream.seek(0)                       # stream terug op begin zetten

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('192.168.137.1', 5005))
size = 1024

while(1):
    strng = my_stream.readline(512)
    # print(strng)
    if not strng:
        break
    client_socket.send(strng)

my_stream.close()

msg = client_socket.recv(512)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
print("Data Sent successfully")
```

If I comment out the final lines from this code, the image gets sent to the directory from my computer. With it, it gets stuck.

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please try to construct a minimal, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client sends image data to the server but it does not do anything to notify the server that all of the image data has been sent.  Since the server does not know that the complete image has been received, it is still waiting in `client_socket.recv` for more data to arrive.  That means that the server never reaches the `client_socket.sendall` call, and that means that the client will wait forever in `its client_socket.recv` for data that will never arrive, because it was never sent.

It works, sort of, when you remove the `client_socket.recv` and following lines from the client because that lets the client process reach the end of the program and exit.  When the client exits, its `client_socket` is closed and that breaks the connection to the server.  The connection drop causes the server's `client_socket.recv` to return with no data, which breaks the server out of the `while True` loop and lets it continue on to save the data that was received earlier and then process the image file.

To fix, in the client call:

```py
client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
```

after all of the image data has been sent.  It can go before the `break` inside the `while(1)` loop, or next to `my_stream.close`, it doesn't matter.

That will tell the server that no more data will be arriving from the client, but it will still allow the socket to carry data in the server-to-client direction.  That will allow the client to collect the server's `pred` response.